# Read from URL in Groovy (with redirect)

Tags: groovy, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

This Groovy code outputs an empty string:

```
def url = 'http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwiki&titles=Mozambique&format=xml&props='.toURL()
print url.getText('utf-8')
```

With the same URL, `curl` also returns empty, but `curl -L` returns the XML I want.
Is there something for Groovy that is similar to that `-L` option?

> -L: If  the  server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new place.

Answer (score 2):

Groovy uses Java's `HttpUrlConnection` under the covers, which doesn't automatically follow redirects. However,here is a small function that will handle it for you by checking the status and location header on the response and call the redirected URL if necessary:

```
def findRealUrl(url) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = url.openConnection()
    conn.followRedirects = false
    conn.requestMethod = 'HEAD'
    if(conn.responseCode in [301,302]) {
        if (conn.headerFields.'Location') {
          return findRealUrl(conn.headerFields.Location.first().toURL())
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException('Failed to follow redirect')
        }
    }
    return url
}
```

The code can be downloaded on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/sbglasius/3899754).

Comment: did you get a chance to try this solution? Did it work for you?